# Is it possible to return value from jQuery popup modal dialog using window.opener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery UI to make the dialog box. How can I get the return value when the dialog box is open? If I use window.open then I know that I can get the return value by window.opener.

Supposedly a modal dialog box will open when I clicked a button. Then return a value because I want to put condition so the page can be reload if the dialog box does not open.I have tried this method but it does not work:

```
$('#button').click(function (){
        if ($('#dialog').dialog('open')){
        // do something
        };
});
```

Also I only want the return value if the dialog box is open not when click any button in the dialog.Thanks in advance !

Comment: Not in the way that you're trying to, no. Instead of checking if the dialog is open, add a delegated event handler to the button in the modal and handle the event in there

Comment: The dialog is just part of your page, so you can access its content the same way as if it wasn't a dialog.

Comment: *"Is it possible to return value from jQuery popup modal dialog using window.opener"* - no, clearly not, as it's not in a window.  Perhaps you'd like to reword your question to something like:  *"How to return value from jQuery popup modal dialog, similar to window.opener"